# symfony2 yui_compressor output in subdomain

Tags: symfony, yui-compressor, output

I'm using yui_compressor:

`

```
{% javascripts filter='?yui_js'
   '@MyProjectBundle/Resources/public/js/libs/jquery/jquery-min.js'
   '@MyProjectBundle/Resources/public/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js'
   '@MyProjectBundle/Resources/public/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip-2.0.js'
   '@MyProjectBundle/Resources/public/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js'
   '@MyProjectBundle/Resources/public/js/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js'
   '@MyProjectBundle/Resources/public/js/main.js' %}
   <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
   <script>
      window.basePath = "{{ url('index') }}";
   </script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

`

I'd like to have an output in subdomain, not in /js/xxx.js, probably one folder above than kernel_root (where my subdomain is pointing in).

Any idea about how could I solve this issue?

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 0):

i use for my assets a cdn.

you can easily change it in the config_prog.yml

```
framework:
templating:
    assets_base_urls:
        http: [ http://cdn.domain.com ]
```

but you have to keep in mind also assets like images and so on are loaded from there...

besides it can be useful to bust your cache (e.g. your cdn has a long time expiration). you can do this by adding

```
framework:
    templating:      { engines: ['twig'], assets_version: v1 }
```

to your config.yml.